# How to use Call Message link on UML Communication Diagram?

Tags: architecture, uml, diagram, visual-paradigm

I suppose this is `UML` question. I am very new to it. I am drawing in `Visual Paradigm`.

I created Communication Diagram and drew two `LifeLine` rectangles. Now I want to draw that one rectangle calls a function inside another. But when I am selecting `Call Message` tool and hover mouse on one of the rectangles, then red prohibiting sign appears. Finally I can't connect rectangles with desired link.

My question is how to use `Call Message` link in UML correctly? Should connect other objects with it or setup connecting objects first somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup the workflow as follows:
1) Create an Actor using the diagram tool bar on the left
2) Create a Lifeline rectangle that interacts with the actor by hovering your mouse on top of the Actor and press and drag the lifeline (message- lifeline arrow, 45 degrees to the right)
3)  Release the mouse and now move the black arrow (for the message association), appropriately
4) Select this rectangle and do the same as in step 2

You can setup the message associations as you develop the uml diagram